# unable to add custom facebook app "hello world" by another user

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have create a facebook app simple "hello world" using html.
Now i want other fb user to search and add my app.

How do i proceed.
I have made my app public.(still)

through other user,i am able to search my app.
but there is no option to add it or register it to second user's page.

Any help please all i need i that other user accepts(registers) my app.
so that i am able to send notifications to him.

I have create a facebook app simple "hello world" using html.
Now i want other fb user to search and add my app.

How do i proceed.
I have made my app public.(still)

through other user,i am able to search my app.
but there is no option to add it or register it to second user's page.

Any help please all i need i that other user accepts(registers) my app.
so that i am able to send notifications to him.